change from 4 digit version in play store to 3
I am currently creating a new app in react native with Expo to replace an existing app in app- and play store.
The issue im having is that the current version of the app published to play store has version (1.0.0.0), and the app I am trying to submit has version (3.2.0). Publishing to app store is no issue as that is already 3 digits.
I get the following error message when submitting to play store:
Google Api Error: Invalid request - You cannot rollout this release because it does not allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs. - Retrying...

Apple doesnt allow for more than 3 digits, while I cant find out how to reduce the version number size for the play store? I would like both app versions in both stores to be the same.
Any ideas?

"1.0.0.0", "3.2.0" or whatever string refers to the user-facing version which is shown in stores. In Android context it is versionName.
Increase versionCode to make the update. The value is a positive integer. It is the developer-facing build version for Android, which is used to check for an upgrade or downgrade.
See App version management for details
